# Git linked directory (always in sync)

Tags: git, github

I'm using GitHub to host two repos, they both contain a directory named "lib", this directory is exactly the same in both repos. At the minute every time I modify the contents of the "lib" directory in one of the repos, I have to copy and paste the newly modified "lib" directory to the other repo then push it to GitHub. I was just wondering if their was a better way to do this, where the "lib" directory is only in one repo and somehow linked inside the other repo so I only have to modify the contents of the "lib" directory once and they are always both in sync with each other.

Answer (score 1):

Depending what you have in `lib` it might be worth extracting the shared files out into their own repo, and using a dependency manager like [bower](http://bower.io) or [bundler](http://bundler.io) to keep each project on the correct version.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a submodule from this directory. http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

Answer (score 0):

Git submodules are often awkward to deal with.  You may well be better off using [git-subtree](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt).  Just like with git submodules, this would require a separate repo which contains the contents of the `lib` directory, and then you use `git subtree` to synchronise changes between this and the other two repos.